# ant.concat task translation to Gradle / Groovy

Tags: ant, gradle

```
        <concat destfile="${database_dir}/xxxx-create-constraints.sql">
        <filelist dir="${database_dir}" files="XXXX-hsqldb-nodrop.sql" />
        <filterchain>
            <striplinebreaks />
            <replacestring from=";" to=";&#10;" />
            <linecontains>
                <contains value="add constraint" />
            </linecontains>
        </filterchain>
    </concat>
    <concat destfile="${database_dir}/XXXXX-drop-constraints.sql">
        <filelist dir="${database_dir}" files="xxxx-hsqldb.sql" />
        <filterchain>
            <striplinebreaks />
            <replacestring from=";" to=";&#10;" />
            <linecontains>
                <contains value="drop constraint" />
            </linecontains>
        </filterchain>
    </concat>
```

I am trying to translate this into Gradle, it is part of a larger task the majority of which I have already translated, I am having trouble with the following section.

```
<filterchain>
            <striplinebreaks />
            <replacestring from=";" to=";&#10;" />
            <linecontains>
                <contains value="drop constraint" />
            </linecontains>
        </filterchain>
```

I can't find any examples or documentation on how this might look in Groovy.
Thus far I have just:

```
    ant.concat(destFile:"${database_dir}/XXXX-create-constraints.sql"){
    files("XXXX-hsqldb-nodrop.sql")
    filelist(dir:"${database_dir}")

}
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

EDIT
I've nutted out a version though I'm not sure about correctness, just because its not throwing errors or breaking doesn't mean its right.

```
    ant.concat(destFile:"${database_dir}/XXXX-create-constraints.sql"){
    files("XXXX-hsqldb-nodrop.sql")
    filelist(dir:"${database_dir}")
    filterchain{
       striplinebreaks()
       replacestring(from:';', to:';&#10;')
       linecontains{
           'add constraint'
       }
   }
}
```